# Android emulator crashes:

Tags: flutter, android-emulator, android-camera, macos-sonoma

I recently upgraded my MacOS M1 version to macOS Sonoma 14.0.

Before the update and upgrade the `camera` of my flutter android emulator worked very well. But after the update, whenever I open my camera of my project on my emulator, the emulator crashes. What should I do?

My

minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 33
compileSdkVersion 33

Any help?